# jquery copy html content without the child content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to copy the html content of an ul element without it's child element to an input box (to the value parameter) with jquery. Is it possible to do that?

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="from">
    <li>test 1<button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button></li>
    <li>test 2<button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button></li>
    <li>test 3<button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button></li>                            </ul>

<input type="text" id="to" value="...">
<button type="button" id="btn" valu="copy">COPY</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function()
                     {
                       $('#to').val($('#from').html());
                     });
    });
</script>
```

I would like to see these modified li elements (without buttons):

```
<li>test 1</li>
<li>test 2</li>
<li>test 3</li>
```

And this would be the result input tag:

```
<input type="text" id="to" value="<li>test 1</li><li>test 2</li><li>test 3</li>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) unwanted elements:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#to').val($('#from').clone()
           .find('button').remove().end().html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="from">
    <li>test 1
        <button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button>
    </li>
    <li>test 2
        <button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button>
    </li>
    <li>test 3
        <button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="to" value="...">
<button type="button" id="btn" valu="copy">COPY</button>
```

Comment: Haha you're faster than me ;)

Answer (score 1):

clone it and remove the buttons.

```
var temp = $('#from').clone()
temp.find("button").remove()
console.log(temp.html())
```

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var clone = $("#from").clone();
    clone.find("button").remove();
    $('#to').val(clone.html().replace(/ /g, ""));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="from">
    <li>test 1<button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button></li>
    <li>test 2<button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button></li>
    <li>test 3<button type="button" class="delete">DEL</button></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="to" value="...">
<button type="button" id="btn" valu="copy">COPY</button>
```